# What does @ mean?

Tags: bash, curl

Here's the code I'm looking at:

```
#!/bin/bash
nc -l 8080 &

curl "http://localhost:8080" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data @<(cat <<EOF
{
  "me": "$USER",
  "something": $(date +%s)
}
EOF
)
```

What does the `@` do?  Where is there documentation about `@`?

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d

Comment: Aside: I don't see the benefit of this construct here (`@` and process substitution), why not simply `-d '{"me": '"$USER"',"something":'"$(date +%s)"'}'`?

Comment: @BenjaminW.  Good point.  That is just some code I found, and I was wondering how it worked.  It is a little cleaner without all the quotes, though.

Comment: `'{"me": "'"$USER"'","something":'"$(date +%s)"'}'` this would produce the same data with the quotes around user. Also, the `@`, `cat` and process substitution really unnecessary and inefficient.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Right, I dropped a pair of quotes there.

Comment: Note that `curl ... --data @- <<EOF` would have been simpler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a curl-specific symbol. [`man curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) shows you:

```
-d, --data <data>

(HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the
(same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and
(presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the
(server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Compare to
(-F, --form.

--data-raw is almost the same but does not have a special interpretation of
the @ character. To post data purely binary, you should instead use the
--data-binary option. To URL-encode the value of a form field you may use
--data-urlencode.

If any of these options is used more than once on the same command line, the
data pieces specified will be merged together with a separating &-symbol.
Thus, using '-d name=daniel -d skill=lousy' would generate a post chunk that
looks like 'name=daniel&skill=lousy'.

If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file name to
read the data from, or - if you want curl to read the data from stdin.
Multiple files can also be specified. Posting data from a file named
'foobar' would thus be done with -d, --data @foobar. When --data is told to
read from a file like that, carriage returns and newlines will be stripped
out. If you don't want the @ character to have a special interpretation use
--data-raw instead.

See also --data-binary and --data-urlencode and --data-raw. This option
overrides -F, --form and -I, --head and -T, --upload-file.
```

Comment: +1. It's probably worth mentioning that the rest of the argument, the `<(...)`, is replaced by [Bash's *process substitution* feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) with a filename from which can be read the output of the command in `...`.

Comment: @ruakh, Thanks!  That was the next confusing bit for me.  I was trying to figure out how to ask about that, and then your comment appeared.